# Create a type liblas.point.Point in order to save a *.las file with Liblas module

Tags: python, formatting, type-conversion, lidar

I have a data set as:

```
 s
'308342.38 6964462.78 122.15 16 1 1 0 0 1 0 114.985 7.1653 '

type (s)
<type 'str'>
```

what i wish to do is create a liblas.point.Point and save it (there are several milion of points) in a *.las file

```
file_out = lasfile.File(outFile,mode='w')
```

this is the message error:

```
file_out.write(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\liblas\file.py", line 382, in write
'be of type liblas.point.Point' % pt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Point` instances just by instantiating it:

```
pt = liblas.point.Point()
```

Then, you just fill in its fields (`x`, `y`, `z`, etc.) and `write` it.

Comment: yes really thanks!!!!. Do you think is convenient create an "header" to associate at the new file?

Comment: How do you fill in its fields and how do you write it?